# When I export Google My Maps to KML (or KMZ) it doesn't include <Point> value

Tags: excel, google-maps, kml, mymaps

I want to export the data from My Maps to a KML file to use elsewhere, however, it is missing the Point data I need for the PlaceMarker. It seems like there should be a way to include this, because clicking on a point shows the Latitude and Longitude underneath the description, but I have a large number of points and don't want to hard code each one. I put sample code of what I'm talking about below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Test</name>
        <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
        <Folder>
            <name>address.xlsx</name>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Buffet</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: Jimmy<br>Address: Somewhere on the Beach<br>City: Key West<br>State: FL<br>ZIP: 33040]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>Jimmy</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>Somewhere on the Beach</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>Key West</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>FL</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>33040</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>Somewhere on the Beach Key West FL 33040</address>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Bush</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: George<br>Address: 1600 Pennsylvania Ave<br>City: Washington<br>State: DC<br>ZIP: 20500]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>George</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>1600 Pennsylvania Ave</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>Washington</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>DC</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>20500</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>1600 Pennsylvania Ave Washington DC 20500</address>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Crockett</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: Davey<br>Address: The Alamo<br>City: San Antonio<br>State: TX<br>ZIP: 78210]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>Davey</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>The Alamo</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>San Antonio</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>TX</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>78210</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>The Alamo San Antonio TX 78210</address>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Gates</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: Bill<br>Address: 1 Microsoft Way<br>City: Redmond<br>State: WA<br>ZIP: 98052]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>Bill</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>1 Microsoft Way</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>Redmond</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>WA</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>98052</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>1 Microsoft Way Redmond WA 98052</address>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Kong</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: King<br>Address: Empire State Building<br>City: New York<br>State: NY<br>ZIP: 10118]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>King</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>Empire State Building</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>New York</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>NY</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>10118</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>Empire State Building New York NY 10118</address>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Rockne</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: Knute<br>Address: 146 Keenan Hall<br>City: Notre Dame<br>State: IN<br>ZIP: 46556]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>Knute</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>146 Keenan Hall</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>Notre Dame</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>IN</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>46556</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>146 Keenan Hall Notre Dame IN 46556</address>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Simpson</name>
                <description><![CDATA[First: Homer<br>Address: 742 Evergreen Terrace<br>City: Springfield<br>State: US<br>ZIP: 12345]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='First'>
                        <value>Homer</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='Address'>
                        <value>742 Evergreen Terrace</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='City'>
                        <value>Springfield</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='State'>
                        <value>US</value>
                    </Data>
                    <Data name='ZIP'>
                        <value>12345</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <address>742 Evergreen Terrace Springfield US 12345</address>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
        <Style id='icon-503-DB4436-normal'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff3644DB</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0.0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id='icon-503-DB4436-highlight'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff3644DB</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id='icon-503-DB4436'>
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-normal</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-highlight</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

[You can see in this photo the latitude and longitude displayed to the bottom left of the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENvCI.jpg)

Comment: batchgeo.com does allow for importing multiple pins, and exports to KML with the Point value, but it loses a lot of the description data

Comment: Could you cut and paste any relevant code instead of posting it as an image?

Comment: Have you tried using geoxml3? the geoxml3 is an effort to develop a KML processor for use with v3 of the Google Maps JS API. This library was originally intended to fill that need. For more info, you may check this link: https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3

Comment: That does look promising, but I'm not using Google Maps JavaScript API, I'm using API for Android Studio programming in Java, because i want to use their KmlLayers. I'm not sure if the KmlLayer will recognize the geoxml3

Comment: Consider using a Fusion Table(FT) instead of MyMaps. The FT data can be downloaded. When you create a new object on Google Drive there is an option for "More" with an option for Fusion Table.

Comment: Update: This may be a result of the fact that KmlLayer in Android Studio is still in beta, but the <address> attribute of the Placemark should be enough to place it on the map. However, according to Google's kml importing utility for Android, <address> is only "partially supported" and "stored as a property value". Therefore, Google MyMaps isn't the problem, Android Studio's interpretation of kml is